# Codeigniter POST is empty when image data is sent

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using [Rest Controller library](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) in Codeigniter project for my APIs. For one of the Post Services, I have the data, something like this

```
{
    title: "My Test Title",
    category: "Sports",
    description: "<p>This is my Html Based description<p>",
    image: "data:image/png;base64,..............(the complete image data)"
}
```

**Problem**
Whenever, I send data to the server along with `image`, `$_POST` becomes empty. When I remove `image`, things work perfectly fine.

**What I have tried**
1. I have used `$_POST`, `$this->post()`, `$this->input->post()`, all are empty.
2. Content length is **183.91KB**, while the `post_max_size` is **8M**.
3. In my .htaccess file, I have used `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]` as well.

Can anyone please help, how can I get the data in normal flow without using `file://input`?

It works fine when Api is called on localhost.

Comment: add form code in ur ques

Comment: I am using [Rest Controller library](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) in Codeigniter project for my APIs.
 @B.K

Comment: can you try to send your image content and not the data image base 64 ?  [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet can be used to read the input stream.

```
$raws=file_get_contents("file://input");

$inputs=json_decode($raws,true);

print_r($inputs);
```